# joining two tables with same field to multiple columns

Tags: mysql

i have a table user

`id   firstname    lastname 
1   | Kenny      | Kim
2   | Smith      | Lt
3   | James      | Wagh 
4   | Wales      | St 
5   | Stephen    | Mathew`

teams table

`tid  manager  teams 
1     2          3
2     2          4
3     5          1`

I want the result to be 

`Manager     Team Mates
Smith Lt    James Wagh, Wales St, Kenny Kim`

I am not getting how to join. plz do suggest.

Comment: Look at [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: What is stored in `teams` column of the `teams` table?

Comment: @Paul Spiegel : ids of the users from users table

Comment: @user3368088  How do you know that the First Team (with tid = 1) has such Team Mates ? (James Wagh, Wales St, Kenny Kim). It is not determined.

Comment: Is a team identified by its manager?

Comment: @ Július Marko: Manager column in teams table is again the IDs of users from users table. Admin will define who is going to manage whose.

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel: Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select concat(m.firstname, ' ', m.lastname) as Manager,
       group_concat(concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) separator ', ') as `Team Mates`
from teams t
join user m on m.id = t.manager
join user u on u.id = t.teams
group by t.manager
```

Answer (score -1):

Study Joins in Mysql, and try to solve your problem yourself. The Following link can help you a lot.

[Joins in mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: please to use comments section for such answer. Or edit it with full detailed answer if you find appropriate